# Podcasts app *starting* unexpectedly

Tags: macos, podcasts.app

Recently I have observed the Podcasts app *opening* unexpectedly on my mac, roughly once a month but with no pattern I've been able to identify. This interrupts me from doing what I actually want to do, so I want to prevent the app from opening. As I do all my podcast listening through my phone, I would be happy to delete the app from my mac, though this appears to not be possible — there no "Move to Bin" option in the contextual menu for most of the pre-installed Apple apps, and the `File > Delete Immediately` menu item is disabled.

Given my goal is to stop being interrupted, any suggestions why might the app be opening without any apparent action on my part, *or* how can I delete the app from my mac?

- `Preferences > Users & Groups > (me) > Login items` is empty
- `Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` does not list any keyboard shortcuts associated with Podcasts.app
- MacOS 11.6 (20G165)
- Podcast.app 1.1.0 (1575.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen time lets you block apps. I would add it there first and then see if your media play F8 keyboard triggers the app.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-screen-time-for-yourself-mchle4e2edfe/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-time-limits-for-apps-and-websites-mchl630bc02f/mac
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436

[Also watch the dock for continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681). If you’re listening on another device the Mac may be too helpful in wanting to carry on what your other device started. I use overcast on my devices so I don’t get [this specific handoff](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209455).